# How do I to make watermark image with PHP and GD like envato photodune preview image?

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation, watermark

I would like to create watermark with PHP and GD library.

I would like to do repeating the **watermark logo** with auto margin(space) between each repeated logo, also zigzag position.

Is it possible to create **dash line watermark** that connect each watermark logo?

The result would be like this:

[image]

---

I have finished the zigzag by using loop function and odd even clause.

```
/*
             * utils
                $widthWatermark = imagesx($logo);
                $heightWatermark = imagesy($logo);
                $widthPhoto = imagesx($output);
                $heightPhoto = imagesy($output);
             */

            // $xLogoPosition = 0;
            // $yLogoPosition = 0;


            $__xRepeat = ceil($widthPhoto / $widthWatermark);
            $__yRepeat = ceil($heightPhoto / $heightWatermark);
            $margin = (int)self::$option['margin'];

            for ($i = 0; $i <= $__xRepeat; $i++) {

                if ($i % 2 === 0) { 
                    $pre_ii = 1;
                } else {
                    $pre_ii = 0;
                }

                for ($ii = 0; $ii <= $__yRepeat; $ii++) {

                    $ii_zero = $ii - $pre_ii;

                    if ($ii_zero % 2 === 0) {       
                        $y_xindent = $widthWatermark;                        
                    }else{
                        $y_xindent = 0;  
                    }

                    $this->imagecopymerge_alpha($output, $logo, ($xLogoPosition + $widthWatermark * $i + $y_xindent), ($yLogoPosition + $widthWatermark * $ii), 0, 0, ImageSX($logo), ImageSY($logo), self::$option['opacity']);
                }
            }
```

now I stuck at how to create dashed line that have diagonal position that connect to each other logo.

I have a hint from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedashedline.php
but I don't how to use and combine it with my previous code that generate zigzag logo

Comment: Show your attempts so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit***

It turns out that PHP/GD actually has a function - [`imagesettile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesettile.php) - specifically to handle this situation.

I've modified my original answer to account for this:

```
<?php
// create php image of a 'dashed cross'.
$crossW = $crossH = 200;
$cross  = imagecreatetruecolor($crossW, $crossH);
imagefill($cross, 0, 0, 0x7fff00ff); // transparent magenta.
imagesetthickness($cross, 1);
imagesetstyle(
    $cross,
    array_merge(
        array_fill(0, 3, 0x7fff00ff), // transparent magenta.
        array_fill(0, 8, 0x60ffffff) // partially-transparent white.
    )
);
imageline($cross, 0, 0, $crossW, $crossH, IMG_COLOR_STYLED);
imageline($cross, $crossW, 0, 0, $crossH, IMG_COLOR_STYLED);

$imageFile = 'wm2.jpg';

// open the image file to be watermarked and store its height and width.
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
$imWidth = imagesx($image);
$imHeight = imagesy($image);

// apply the cross pattern as a tile to the image file.
imagesettile($image, $cross);
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $imWidth, $imHeight, IMG_COLOR_TILED);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($cross);
imagedestroy($image);
exit;
```

Input:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: @user3681874: Tim's approach will work for that - just change the size of the dash-cross square, and modify the offset if necessary. Give it a go?

Comment: @user3681874, okay - [see here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetstyle.php).